# Invisible ReCaptcha with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am trying to implement the newest ReCaptcha (aka "invisible" ReCaptcha) within an form using jQuery and an "ajax" request.
ReCaptcha documentation: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

My form:

```
<form id="myForm" >
    <input type="email" name="email" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br/>
    <!--<input type="submit" value="log in" />-->
    <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdK..." data-callback="onSubmit">log in</button>
</form>
<div id="status"></div>
```

My javascript (jQuery):

```
<script>

    function onSubmit(token){
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var datas = $("#myForm").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                data: datas,
                dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#status").html("logging in...");
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#status").html(response.text);
                        if(response.type=="success"){
                            window.location.replace("/myaccount");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $("#status").html("Failed.");
                    }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

ReCaptcha requires to set a "data-callback", which I am not sure how to bind with my already existing ".submit(function(event)" function.
My "onSubmit()" trick did not work, it ignores the "ajax" and refreshes the page.

How do I send the "g-recaptcha-response" value within my "datas" variable to POST it to test.php?

Comment: @13h15 I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @VinZ Yes, posting it ASAP

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So here is how I solved it after digging further in Invisible reCAPTCHA's doc, and learning a bit of jQuery obviously since I was not very familiar with JS (cool stuff):

My head tag with the javascript (and a bit of css to remove the ugly Google badge):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&hl=fr" async defer></script>

<style>
    .grecaptcha-badge{
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    var onloadCallback = function(){
        grecaptcha.render("emplacementRecaptcha",{
            "sitekey": "YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY_HERE",
            "badge": "inline",
            "type": "image",
            "size": "invisible",
            "callback": onSubmit
        });
    };
    var onSubmit = function(token){
        var userEmail = $("#userEmail").val();
        var userPassword = $("#userPassword").val();
        var userTfaOtp = $("#userTfaOtp").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: location.href,
            data:{
                    userEmail: userEmail,
                    userPassword: userPassword,
                    userTfaOtp: userTfaOtp,
                    userJetonRecaptcha: token
                },
            dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#statutConnexion").html("Traitement de votre requête d'authentification en cours...");
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $("#statutConnexion").html(response.Message);
                    if(response.Victoire){
                        $("#formulaireConnexion").slideUp();
                        window.location.replace("/compte");
                    }
                    else{
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("#statutConnexion").html("La communication avec le système d'authentification n'a pas pu être établie. Veuillez réessayer.");
                    grecaptcha.reset();
                }
        });
    };
    function validate(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#statutConnexion").html("Validation de votre épreuve CAPTCHA en cours...");
        grecaptcha.execute();
    }
    function onload(){
        var element = document.getElementById("boutonConnexion");
        element.onclick = validate;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="formulaireConnexion">
    <input type="email" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" placeholder="Courriel" title="Courriel" required="required" /><br />
    <input type="password" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" placeholder="Mot de passe" title="Mot de passe" required="required" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="userTfaOtp" id="userTfaOtp" placeholder="Double authentification (optionnelle)" autocomplete="off" pattern="[0-9]{6}" title="Six caractères numériques" maxlength="6" /><br />
    <div id="emplacementRecaptcha"></div>
    <button id="boutonConnexion">Connexion</button>
</div>
<div id="statutConnexion"></div>
<script>onload();</script>
```

Let me know if you need the whole PHP as well since it's out of the scope of this question. You will probably need to change "url: location.href," within the JS above since in my case the script rendering the HTML form and the JS and dealing with the POST vars is the same (not great, testing purpose). Basically I just verify the POST vars then finally return a json like:

```
$jsonVictoire = true; // boolean
$jsonMessage = 'anything you want to tell your visitor'; // string

$return = 
    json_encode(
        array(
            'Victoire'=>$jsonVictoire,
            'Message'=>$jsonMessage
        )
    );
die($return);
```

Comment: FYI you're breaking google TOS by removing the badge. Just put it somewhere down with data-badge=inline and css

Answer (score 4):

```
<script defer>              
function onSubmit(token) {                      
    var f = $("#myForm");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: f.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#status").html("logging in...");
        },
        success: function(response){
            $("#status").html(response.text);
            if(response.type=="success"){
                window.location.replace("/myaccount");
            } else {
                $("#status").html("Captcha failed.");
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#status").html("Failed.");
        }       
    });
}
</script>
```

In test.php you need to verify captcha on server side:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=[YOUR_SECRET_KEY]&response=$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]&remoteip=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]'), TRUE);

    if($result['success'] == 1) {
        // Captcha ok
    } else {
        // Captcha failed
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `onSubmit` needs to handle/add the `token` to the `$.ajax` call, similar to the approved solution.

Comment: Approved solution was added after mine.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit&onload=onScriptLoad" async defer></script>

<div id="login_page" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible" data-sitekey="your sitekey"  data-callback="login_page"></div>
<script>
    window.onScriptLoad = function () {
// this callback will be called by recaptcah/api.js once its loaded. If we used
// render=explicit as param in script src, then we can explicitly render reCaptcha at this point
// element to "render" invisible captcha in
    var htmlEl = document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha');
// option to captcha
    var captchaOptions = {
          sitekey: 'your site key...',
          size: 'invisible',
          // reference to an actual function
          callback: window.onUserVerified
         };
        // Only for "invisible" type. if true, will read value from html-element's data-* attribute if its not passed via captchaOptions
        var inheritFromDataAttr = true;
        // now render
        recaptchaId = window.grecaptcha.render(htmlEl, captchaOptions, inheritFromDataAttr);
    };
    window.onUserVerified = function (token){
       Your ajax code....
    }
     $("#blog_inquiry").click(function(e){
            //var gg = grecaptcha.getresponse();
        var token =   window.grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptchaId);
        // if no token, mean user is not validated yet
        if (!token) {
             window.grecaptcha.execute(recaptchaId);
             return;
        }
        });
</script>`
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).